# SSIS - Look Up Range from another table

Tags: ssis

I have a Table A which includes a StartTime and EndTime.  I am trying to fetch a group of rows from Table B where the SourceTime is between Table A StartTime and EndTime.  I am looking to get the Min, Max and Average of a column on Table B to be part of my results.

Ex Result:

```
Table A Id
Table A StartTime
Table A EndTime
Table B ValColumn_Min
Table B ValColumn_Max
Table B ValColumn_Avg
```

I have an OLE DB Source that is getting Table A.  From there, what is the best way to get this result

Comment: Is Table B from the same source as Table A? If yes, could you try joining them in your query?

Comment: They are same source and could but i want to leverage SSIS and not have it be all query based

Comment: If this is a learning exercise, sure try and do it all in SSIS but from a complexity perspective, it's going to be way easier in a query than trying to cobble it together with dataflow components..

Comment: In table B, what are we min/max/avg ing?

Comment: Table B is a data source that we are getting at 1 sec intervals which has a SourceTime as its Stamp.  I am trying to get all Rows from Table B that Correlate to 1 Row of Table A.  Then take the Min, Max and Average of Table B Value column which is a float.  This way when i write Table A to my Warehouse it is flattened with the Min Max Avg of Table B values within it

Answer (score 1):

## The SQL Query approach

I'm not totally sure on this as I have no table structure of values to work with but the idea is that we want to use the SourceTime from B and pin it between a range in A. We'll group by the A table's ID/StartTime/EndTime and roll up summary statistics for the B row(s).

```
SELECT
  A.Id
, A.StartTime
, A.EndTime
, MIN(B.ValColumn) AS ValColumn_Min
, MAX(B.ValColumn) AS ValColumn_Max
, AVG(B.ValColumn) AS ValColumn_Avg
FROM
    dbo.A AS A
    INNER JOIN dbo.B AS B
    ON B.SourceTime >= A.StartTime AND B.SourceTime < A.EndTime
GROUP BY
  A.Id
, A.StartTime
, A.EndTime;
```

If that's not yielding the expected results, remove the grouping and the aggregate functions and look at the raw values from B and see if that is showing what is expected.

## The Data Flow approach

The devil you're going to run into is that a Lookup by default is an exact match operation (`col_1 == col_a`) but you need to do advanced comparisons (which is fine, just not an level 1 SSIS package). The other thing to note is that a lookup will only ever return at most 1 row. It might find 0.

Why that's going to matter is that we need to start with the B table as the driver because I assume a row in B will only ever find one row in A. A range in A may find multiple rows in B.

[image]

### OLE_SRC B

I'd select the data strictly needed for the package. In this case, it looks like I'd use a query of

```
SELECT B.SourceTime, B.ValColumn
FROM dbo.B AS B
```

and possibly a `WHERE` clause in there otherwise you're re-processing all the data.

### LKP A

Add a Lookup component

On the General tab, specify the Cache Mode of "No cache" because we're going to issue a query for each row coming through.

On the Connection tab, and again, only pull in what is needed so I'm going to specify the columns I need from our table via a SQL Query.

```
SELECT A.Id, A.StartTime, A.EndTime
FROM dbo.A AS A
```

That's the start of the query but we'll have to fiddle with it in a bit.

In the columns tab, drag the `SourceTime` column and link it to `StartTime` and then check the Id/StartTime/EndTime from the Available Lookup Columns

In the advanced tab, click Modify the SQL Statement and then use the following

```
declare @sourceTime int = ?
select * from (SELECT A.Id, A.StartTime, A.EndTime
FROM dbo.A AS A) [refTable]
where [refTable].[StartTime] <= @sourceTime  and [refTable].EndTime > @sourceTime
```

An OLE DB Connection uses the question mark `?` as a zero based ordinal parameter system. Since we need to use the `SourceTime` twice in our query, we're going to "cheat" and declare a TSQL variable in our query and populate it. Then we'll re-use that variable in our query.

You'll note that in my example, I have the data type for Start/End/Source time as integer and that's by design because I don't know if you're working with datetime or datetime2 and at what precision. The concept is the same regardless of the actual typing.

I also have the order of the comparison flipped in the SQL query approach vs the lookup component. Both evaluate correctly but I'd already taken the screenshots when I noticed it.

Lots of work to get there with the Data Flow approach, plus it's going to be slower given that it must make a query for each row passing through plus the native query could likely make better use of indexes but this is how I'd do it if forced to do the heavy lifting in SSIS components.